# Available file system content types in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems, fs

I'm new to NodeJs and want to save a file in my nodeJs app.i I have implemented some code with the help of google. it works and saved my file as a text file. but I want to save .dat extension type file if there any possible way to do so.
here is my implemented code,

```
 fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.txt', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!');
          });
```

and I import the fs using,

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: change `'mynewfile1.txt'` to `'mynewfile1.dat'`

Comment: @Yousaf thanks it worked 